# Why a router used as access point is causing me problems

Tags: wireless-access-point, packet-loss

I have two modems/routers but was just using one for the entire home. Since I wanted to have Wi-Fi in the first floor as well I connected my second device to the first one with an Ethernet cable so it could create another network over there. The problem is that sometimes I just lose both wired and wireless connection in my main router. However, if I disconnect that Ethernet cable (the one connecting the two routers) and wait some seconds, everything gets back to normal. Also, sometimes I have internet both wired and wirelessly but my Google Home would have some problems streaming music and that's something that didn't happen when I was using just one router. It's like the main network has some packet loss problem but when I ping on my computers meanwhile I don't see any drop.

For now I'm just assuming one (if not both) of my devices is just not good enough to handle 10-15 connections and making that AP movement just made things worse.

Devices are: ZTE F660 (main) and TP-Link TD-W8968

If you need any further information, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you turned off DHCP on the second router?

Comment: Which device is primary and which is AP?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft I don't think so. I'll do it when I get back from work and see what happens.

Comment: @Tyson ZTE is primary device and TP-Link is the AP.

Comment: Found a vid on setting up 8968 as an access point https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fAjaHgwNts4

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft yeah, that worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: @Tyson thanks, it helped me a lot getting it set correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must configure the TP-link as a WiFi Acess Point (AP) only.

Otherwise it is competing with your main router to offer DHCP service and is likely to be causing IP-address conflicts depending on which router gets its DHCP response out quickest and how far the DHCP pools overlap.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the answer. Running perfectly right now :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a router as an access point that worked fine for a long time, but then started to slow down the network. I know this because once turned off, speed returned to normal (and vice versa).

I solved the problem by turning off EVERYTHING in the router used as an AP, not just DHCP. So I turned off all IPv6 handling, UPNP etc etc making the AP router as dumb s possible. And then all worked perfectly again!

Just to be clear the router used as an AP did not have an AP mode option.